# Unable to access the function in the contract using hardhat ethers

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, hardhat, uniswap

This is the smart contract code :-

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

interface  IUniswapRouter {
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function swapExactETHForTokens(
        uint amountOutMin, // The minimum amount of output tokens that must be received for the transaction not to revert
        address[] calldata path, //An array of token addresses
        address to, // Destination address
        uint deadline
    ) // Unix timestamp after which the transaction will revert
    external payable returns (uint[] memory amounts); 

    function WETH() external pure returns (address);

}

interface IERC20{
     function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);

    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

interface IWETH is IERC20 {
    function deposit() external payable;

    function withdraw(uint amount) external;
}

contract  Swaps {

    address private constant router =  0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;

    address private constant usdt = 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7;
    address private constant usdc = 0x8AC76a51cc950d9822D68b83fE1Ad97B32Cd580d;


    IUniswapRouter private uniswapRouter = IUniswapRouter(router);
    IERC20 private USDT = IERC20(usdt);
    IERC20 private USDC = IERC20(usdc);

    function swapEthforTokens(uint amountOutMin) external returns (uint amountOut) {
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = uniswapRouter.WETH();
        path[1] = usdt;

        uint[] memory amounts = uniswapRouter.swapExactETHForTokens(amountOutMin,path,msg.sender,block.timestamp);

        return amounts[1];
    }

  

    function swapSingleHopExactAmountIn(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin
    ) external returns (uint amountOut) {
        USDT.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this),amountIn);
        USDT.approve(address(router),amountIn);

        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);

        path[0] = usdt;
        path[1] = usdc;

        uint[] memory amounts = uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn,amountOutMin,path,msg.sender,block.timestamp);

        return amounts[1];

    }

}
```

while this is the deploy script code :-

```
    const {network} = require("hardhat")

module.exports = async function ({getNamedAccounts,deployments}){
    console.log("Entered the deployment");
    await console.log(getNamedAccounts);
    const {deploy,log} = deployments
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts()

    
    
    log("------------------------------")

    const args= []
    const swaps = await deploy("Swaps",{
        from:deployer,
        args:args,
        log:true,
        waitConfirmations:1
    })

    

    const amountOutMin = ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "wei"); // Adjust this value as needed
    const tx = await swaps.swapEthforTokens(amountOutMin, {
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1"),  // Sending 0.1 Ether, adjust this value as needed
    });

    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log(`swapEthforTokens called in transaction ${receipt.transactionHash}`);
  

    log("--------------------------------------");

 


}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "swaps", "main"]
```

The contract deploys successfully however the error occurs while access the function :-

```
Error running JSON-RPC server: ERROR processing C:\Users\kaush\forking\deploy\01-swaps.js:
TypeError: swaps.swapEthforTokens is not a function
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (C:\Users\kaush\forking\deploy\01-swaps.js:24:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (C:\Users\kaush\forking\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1211:22)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (C:\Users\kaush\forking\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1060:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (C:\Users\kaush\forking\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:442:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (C:\Users\kaush\forking\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:333:14)
    at Environment.run (C:\Users\kaush\forking\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:166:14)
```